# What versions of Java are available on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, version, operating-system

With all the normal Apple updates applied (I.E. No additional effort has been made by the customer to install a particular version of Java), what versions of Java are available for the Tiger, Leopard and Snow Leopard versions of Mac OS X? If it also depends on the hardware 32bit/64bit could you please include this information.

Thank you for your answers.

K.P.Sullivan

Comment: I disagree about the vote to close.  This is about developer tools.

Comment: @kpsullivan: with no additional effort, you must target Java 1.5. There is no Java 1.6 for Tiger and there are a *lot* of MacBook Pro with a 32 bit CPU and Leopard out there that by default do not have Java 1.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire list for Mac OS X <=10.5 is in tables 1, 2, 3 and 4 on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2110.html). I took the 10.6 numbers from my own system. The basics are:

10.6: Java SE 1.6.0 (not on that page)
10.5: Java SE 1.6.0, 1.5.0, 1.4.2
10.4: Java SE 1.5.0, 1.4.2, 1.3.1

10.6 has all Java versions symlinked to 1.6.0 so there doesn't seem to be a real Java 5 or 1.4 VM available. Just a 1.6 one pretending to be an earlier version.

1.5 Seems to be the safest bet, there may still be some people running 10.4. People running earlier versions of Mac OS X would seem to be a dying breed.

Comment: Just in case this is important: Java 5 is the latest version of Java you can get on a PowerPC-based Mac. (Vanilla install, of course)

Answer (score -2):

Snow Leopard is Java 6.  Leopard is Java 5 (and perhaps Java 1.4 if upgraded, not sure).  Tiger is Java 1.4.

Be certain to require that the machines are fully updated from Software Update.

Comment: My PowerBook with Tiger (10.4) has Java 5.